# Can I link items in one list to items in parent site list in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a parent site with several subsites in SharePoint 2010.

I have a list in the parent site (call it Product Backlog) that lists in the subsites (Sprint Backlog) need to be able to link to.

Is this possible in SharePoint 2010? That is, Can I add a lookup field in my subsite lists that points to the parent site list as the source of the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common requirement. Event though there isn't any out-of-the-box solution, there are some workarounds for this. [Check this out](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/397a555c-458b-4943-8f7a-71bb508ec8ec/)